# gnome3 desktop empty (no panels)

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and using GNOME 3. This morning, after an update and a reboot, there was no longer a panel on the desktop. I have two monitors, if that makes any difference. I tried uninstalling any gnome-shell-extensions (I have gnome-shell-extension-prefs and gnome-shell-extension-tool) but it couldn't find any package by those names. I'm not even sure this is the reason that the panel is gone, it happened after an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled the proprietary NVIDIA drivers and now everything works perfectly.